# System.ArgumentNullException in code dealing with XDocument

Tags: c#, linq, exception, null, command-line-arguments

I am using VS to run my code and it throws an exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Xml.Linq.dll. Additional information: Value cannot be null.

However I really couldn't figure out why it happened. The Argument is from command line agrument. Can someone please help me to solove the problem? My code so far:

```
public static XDocument docone;
public static XDocument doctwo;

docone = XDocument.Load(args[3]);
doctwo = XDocument.Load(args[4]);

dealWithXML (docone, doctwo, args);

public static void dealWithXML(XDocument xdoc, XDocument secondxdoc, string[] args)
{
    string select = args[2];
    var xseq = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(select); //exception thrown here
}
```

The XML file is as below:

```
<bookstore> 
   <book> 
       <barcode>10000</barcode> 
       <author> Ben </author>
   </book> 
   <book> 
       <barcode>200000</barcode> 
       <author>Tom </author> 
   </book> 
</bookstore>
```

I used Linqpad to Dump the xseq and it worked. I'm rather confused why.

Comment: Your `select` argument is null :) Give us more information

Comment: Thanks for the repley! "select" is a string from command line argument. I printed it out and it's not null. It is a xpath i.e. bookstore/book.

Comment: Show content of `xdoc` and `select`

Comment: The xml document is like below. I used linqpad to dump xseq and it actually returned the nodes.... I am really confused : `<bookstore>
  <book>
    <barcode>10000</barcode>
    <author> Ben </author>
  </book>
  <book>
    <barcode>200000</barcode>
    <author>Tom </author>
  </book>  </bookstore>`

Comment: what is `args[3]` and `args[4]` . `xdoc.XPathSelectElements("bookstore/book")` works fine for me.

Comment: with static values, works for me too.

Comment: Add the argument values you are using to the question. How are you passing them? In a console window you need to enclose file locations within double quotes `"`. My assumption is that it worked in LINQPad, because you probably hardcoded the parameters and the strings were correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `args[3] = "path to xml" and args[2] = "bookstore/book"`

```
            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(args[3]);    
            var parsedXml = x.XPathSelectElements(args[2]);

            foreach (XElement e in parsedXml)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(((XElement)e.FirstNode).Value);
                Console.WriteLine(((XElement)e.LastNode).Value);
            }
```